# Dangerous path error with pdf document in asp.net web forms site

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

I'm trying to display a pdf document on my site and I get this error:

*System.Web.HttpException: A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (&).*

I tried displaying it in an iframe like I've done before and I get this error. I also get this error if I just create a link directly to the document which also has worked before.
I'm thinking there's something in the web config that I need to set to allow .pdf extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It most likely a security concern since you accesing another site try putting the following in your webconfig

```
<httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters="&lt;,&gt;,*,%,:,\,?" />
```

Comment: Yup. That did it. Thank you!